# MSBuild : Incremental build issue

Tags: msbuild, incremental-build

I have question related to partial build. Scenario is as follows.

I have solution which contains Windows form application project and its supporting class library projects. I am building solution using MSBuild. Before building I change assemblyfile version for each project using msbuild custom task. This causes AssemblyInfo files getting modified. Since assemblyinfo files are modified, msbuild builds every single project even though there are no REAL code changes except change in assemblyInfo file. So everytime I build solution it builds ALL projects where as in ideal case it should have built only those projects where real code changes has happened. Because of this solution build time remains same even if there were changes in single project.
There is another side effect of this. I am publishing this application using clickonce. So every time solution gets build it builds every single project in solution. This cause new hash signature generated for every assembly/exe in manifest file every time I do new build. Due to this when updates to application are published clickonce forces user to download every single dll/exe in application. Whereas ideally only updated (one or two may be) files should have been downloaded on user's system.

Essentially what I want is.
1. Build only those projects which has been modified.
2. Update assemblyfile version for ONLY modified projects.

This way I will be able to reduce build time and solve clickonce issue as well.
Any solution/workaround for this?

Comment: What is your custom task you are using for modifying assembly file version? How do you call this task? Add complete text of target where this task is called.

Comment: This issue is resolved. I got clue from Syed Ibrahim Hashmi's below post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667510/determine-if-msbuild-corecompile-will-run-and-call-custom-target#