# How to create a resource out of an "AssemblyInfo" item

Tags: .net, vb.net, resx

I am working on localizing a legacy application and one thing I am having an issue with is strings that are only found within the AssemblyInfo.  Normally I'd find a string literal and just replace it with a My.Resouce.ResourceName and everything shows up just fine when running in the other language.  This is not the case for AssemblyInfo items.

When attempting to just replace the string with a resource, I get the error: `Constant expression is required`

How do I replace the string for a resource?

**Example:**
This is how it's currently written

```
<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("Application Name")>
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("This is the product's description.")>
```

I try:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("Application Name")>
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription(My.Resources.AppDescription)> 'above error is given
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localize AssemblyInfo.cs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752144/localize-assemblyinfo-cs)

Comment: Basically, you do it on pre-compillation. You can programatically  replace these attributes pre-build, for the language you building it. We use FinalBuilder, for example. And it replaces these attributes with values from variables.

Comment: @T.S. I am not sure why that didn't show up in my search before posting.  Apologies, and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute-parameters need to be constant, so you cannot replace it with a resource. One answer for localizing assembly-attributes would be here: [Localize AssemblyInfo.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752144/localize-assemblyinfo-cs)

Comment: Thanks for posting the link.  I will take a look.

Comment: That doesn't have an accepted answer, and the code foundation I am working with doesn't lend itself well to something like that.