# The AssemblyTitle never changes once set, I want it to be changed per configuration

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-assembly, msbuild-task

I would like to change the text shown in the screenshot below based on the Product name. I know, the text is taken from Assembly.Title property which is a read only property and so can not be changed at runtime. So how do I change it at compile time?
We sell the application to multiple customers and the name of the application should change per customer. We have a configurations for each customer. So at build time, Assembly title should be selected as per the configuration.

[image]

Any suggestion how to solve this?

**Update:**

I tried some of the suggestions given in the comments and I found following:

After I set the text using the assembly info popup from project properties or by changing it directly in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, it is shown correctly in the taskbar.

If I change it again, changed text is not shown in the taskbar ie. it shows all the time the text which was set at **FIRST time**.

I tried deleting files, even restarting the system, but it didn't help.

Then I renamed the file (i.e. exe file) and then it **showed  correctly the changed text**.

If I rename it back to original name, it shows the first set text.

What could be the reasons?

Comment: Possible what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585444/how-can-i-change-assemblyproduct-assemblytitle-using-msbuild

Answer (score 3):

In AssemblyInfo.cs (under Properties in a VisualStudio project), you'll find the assembly title specified in an attribute like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyAssembly")]
```

You should be able to wrap this with compiler constants:

```
#if SOME_MODE
    [assembly: AssemblyTitle("SomeName")]
#else
    [assembly: AssemblyTitle("ADifferentName")]
#endif
```

Comment: Potentially, the OP wants to separate code from build type so that the process can be controlled solely from script. This is a bulletproof way to switch on build config though!

Comment: @Gusdor Unless AssemblyInfo.cs is treated differently, the compiler directive should handle this. The `SOME_MODE` constant can be associated with the desired configuration in the project properties view.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion I tried but it is not changing, please check my updated question.

Comment: @RajeshNaik: it could be that the windows UI just caches the assembly title for display in the jump list. However, since you are sending different versions of the application to different customers this shouldn't be an issue, right? To confirm, try sending the differently-titled version to another machine and check that the right title is displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

*Very old question, but this behaviour never got explained here and it took me way too long.*

You want to change *AssemblyTitle* in *AssemblyInfo.cs* as the other comment pointed out, but for testing it's effect that will not be enough:

Windows caches the AssemblyTitle of binaries.
Either copy the binaries to another location to see the effect of the edits, or delete the entries corresponding to the binary in the registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache
```