# Is it possile to sent build number to csproj as a parameter without using the Build.proj

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am not pretty familiar with msbuild technique.
Currently I have a build.proj in my solution to assign a build number to the exe, by using a following param:

```
      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(BUILD_NUMBER)' != '' ">
<!-- Build Server Number -->
<Version>$(BUILD_NUMBER)Version>
<FileVersion>$(BUILD_NUMBER)FileVersion>
<InformationalVersion>$(BUILD_NUMBER)InformationalVersion></PropertyGroup><Target Name="Version">
<Attrib Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\AssemblyInfo.cs" ReadOnly="False" />
<AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS"
              OutputFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs"
              GenerateClass="true"
              AssemblyCopyright="Copyright © $(Year). All rights reserved."
              AssemblyConfiguration="$(BuildConfiguration)"
              AssemblyVersion="$(Version)"
              AssemblyFileVersion="$(FileVersion)"
              AssemblyInformationalVersion="$(InformationalVersion)" />  </Target>
```

Now I can't use build.proj. Is it any alternative way to assign a build number to csproj?

Comment: How do these parameters end-up in your EXE when you use build.proj? A .csproj file is just a build file as well. You can copy over the relevant bits from the build.proj to the .csproj and it should still work. How do you plan to fill the buildnumber property in the .csproj scenario?

Comment: good question, they ended up in AssemblyInfo.cs file which been edited by Build.proj. I am adding that code to the question

Comment: Your .csproj still references that `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs`?

Comment: And how do you plan to start this build? from the commandline or from VS?

Comment: I am planning to start it from commandline

Comment: see these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623673/578411

Comment: yes, I am still referencing to $(MSBuildProjectDirectory), this is where GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs located.

Answer (score 2):

We generate a `AssemblyInfo.cs` file to put in all assembly attributes we need to define. You could do this on pre-build time if that suits you. There we define the `AssemblyVersion`, `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute and other related attributes.

Those properties will be used compiling the assembly.

Comment: Beat me to it. It should also be noted that you can make this file a linked file, so you can use a single generated file for multiple projects, if necessary.

Comment: @NightOwl888 What we do exactly :)

Comment: can you give me an example of you pre build script where you do that?

Comment: No, it is a very long and complicated ANT build file. Nothing I can isolate quickly. But it is not to hard to generate a file using your favorite programming language.