# Generate executable with desired variables

Tags: c#

I have a program which has a unique user id that only belongs to that user. that id is hard coded and used in a web interface where the user can be shown his computer and not someone else's, so whenever i need to give my program to another user i need to recompile the executable with the new hardcoded executable. so i want to make a simple form that has a textbox for the client id and a compile button, so it compiles an executable with the client id in the textbox hard coded in that executable. How would i go about doing this?
I researched this and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments) but i don't think it can be used in my situation.

My program is used to control your pc with a web interface so lets say i got 1 user on my website that has 2 computers. He would need an executable made for him with his user id that is in the database of my website. But what if i got another user and many more, i need to make thousands of versions of my program.

Also as a side question can this be done on a website let's say i have users on my website and every user has his unique id and i want that id to be hardcoded in my program when they go to download it. please don't focus on this too much as its just a side question.

Comment: Sounds x/y ish. why dont you just use commandline arguments, the mac address, a web service login, or any number of things.

Comment: Why You don't include it in a configuration File, and the user have both the exe and the config ?

Comment: *Unique client id that only belongs to that computer.* FYI If your using this as some kind of security mechanism it would be trivial to circumvent

Comment: @HanyHabib - I suspect the answer is going to be something along the lines of the unwritten requirement in the question - that what the OP has failed to mention is that want it to be *tamper resistant*. And then we go down the usual lines of how this is nigh-unsolvable when code is running on the *users* machine.

Comment: or the pc name, the user login name, the user SID, config file, a unique registry value that you generate, ect ect ect

Comment: Ok let me explain, my program is used to control your pc with a web interface so lets say i got 1 user on my website that has 2 computers. He would need an executable made for him with his user id that is in the database of my website. But what if i got another user and many more, i need to make thousands of versions of my program. Also my program  needs to be just the exe and the config filw can be tweaked by the user which i don't like them doing

Comment: Exactly, don't make 1000s of versions, this is x/y

Comment: If you really really really want to go down this path, create a standard windows dll, with a guid or 64 bit int or something, find the offset and modify it on demand before deplyment... however you are better to solve this otherways, especially if you are using a webapi or wcf capable service anyway, its how everyone else does it

Comment: My website is mostly html with php so i was going to upload that form i mentioned above and let the user compile his own executable, confirming his id with a password of course. Do i have to go this route or is there a way to do it in backend and give executable to user. Also i need the program in exe not dll

Comment: you could use `msbuild` backend, but this still is a very very uncommon why to do things, it just doesn't make sense

Comment: Can you give me some examples or point me to the right direction where to start looking for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think your idea isn't very good, but you made a specific request, so I'll give you a specific response.**

If your program is `msbuild`able, then simply executing

```
msbuild yoursolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

(I'm using the Release/AnyCPU here, but you'll have to use the correct parameters depending on how you normally compile your solution)

through the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` method will big a big step in the right direction.

Clearly before doing it you modify a `.cs` file or a resource that will be included in the program.

Now... the only problem is that with newer Visual Studio/.NET the `msbuild.exe` location can change. The simplest way to solve it is to find it manually, for example open a Visual Studio Command Prompt and do:

```
where msbuild.exe
```

the first path is the one that would be executed if you used the `msbuild.exe` from that command prompt, or use the instructions given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/what-s-new-in-msbuild-15-0)

Comment: ok this can work, but can it be done on a html website backend so it is done automatically?

Comment: @DavidAnastasov You must have the Platform SDK installed in the backend to be able to compile... There is no need of special permissions to use the msbuild

Comment: @DavidAnastasov The simplest thing is that first you try to compile the program with msbuild from a command prompt, see what are the parameters needed and when everything work you try using the `Process.Start`

Comment: @xanatox i saw u implemented p:Configuration and p:Platform, i know these come with evey solution but can i add something like p:UserID= for my project or is it not possible?

Comment: @DavidAnastasov It is easier to modify a source file/a resource file... You can modify a csproj so that the UserID will be written somewhere, but it is black magic :-) much easier to directly modify the files. This is probably a good starting point if you want to know about this black magic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3585444/613130

Comment: yeah man this is amazing, thanks for your help u solved an issue i had for a long time :)